# What is the correct way to use/import Laravel facades?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.3

What is the correct way to import namespace for facades (such as `Hash::make`)?

Do I need to use import like `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash`?

I saw some people using them as `\Hash::make` (from namespaced file, such as controllers created by default) or `Hash::make` (from non-namespaced file, such as routes).

Also [ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) generates facades in the root namespace:

```
namespace {
exit("This file should not be included, only analyzed by your IDE");

class Hash extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash{        
    /** ... */
    public static function make($value, $options = array()){
        return \Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::make($value, $options);
    }
```

But I don't understand why it works if this class is in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\` namespace, not in the root namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are comparing Facades to Aliases.

The `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` is a facade class, but `\Hash` is an alias class to that facade. Have a look at your `config/app.php` and see how they're being mapped:

```
'aliases' => [
    'App'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    // ...
```

You can use either the `\Hash` alias or `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` facade class; both are correct.

In the bootstrapping phase, Laravel uses a service named [`AliasLoader`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php). It takes the aliases array from the `config/app.php`, iterates over all the elements, and creates a queue of `__autoload` functions using PHP's `spl_autoload_register`.

Each `__autoload` function is responsible for creating an alias for the respective facade class by using PHP’s [`class_alias`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) function. As the result, we won’t have to import and alias the classes before using them.

Read more:
[How Laravel Facades Work and How to Use Them Elsewhere](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/)

Comment: hm. I wonder then why all files generated by `artisan make:...` do not use aliases and include full namespace import like `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema` instead of just `\Schema` or `use Schema`

Comment: Don't know what the original authors had in mind, but here's my 2 cents: Both are correct, but clearly, the facade is faster. Donno how much faster, but it works around that autoload queue, so it might be the reason. On the other hand, the existential reason for aliases is their ease of use. You don't have to remember the FQDN of the facade, you just use its fancy alias from the root namespace. When generating code,  that's not the case anymore. So why not ignoring aliases?

Answer (score 5):

in your `config/app.php` file you can see a list of `aliases`. `Hash` is included there, so you can import `Hash` just using `use Hash;`

`\Hash::make`, here `\` is to refer from root namespace. So, you can import the `Hash` on top using `use Hash` or use directly using `\Hash::make`

Comment: It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I think you already got an answer. Please try that.